# Insert multiple rows from another table and get the IDs of inserted rows in SQL Server 2000

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2000

I have table A and table B, table B has the same columns of A and only one extra column x , I want to insert some rows from A to B , and then I want to update each one of these last inserted rows with a new value for column x.

How can I do it in SQL Server 2000?

Now I am using this query in C# code, I select all wanted rows from A and I save it in `DataTable`

```
string Query = "Select * from A where ID = 5";

SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, Conn);
dap.Fill(DataTablle1);

foreach (DataRow row in DataTablle1.Rows)
{
      string query2 = "Insert into B (col a , col b, col x) values ('" + row["col a"] + "','" + row["col b"] + "',3)";
}
```

This way requires many insert statement depending on the number of rows in table A, is there any way to achieve it with minimum number of insert statement?

Comment: what are you trying to do.. once the First Table has been returned you can loop through the DataTable1.Rows like you are already with the exception when you are trying to update `DataTable1.Rows[Y]["X"] you will need to do this in a inner for loop.. there you will assign the values to the empty datatable rows `string query2` what are you wanting to do with this.. you are not showing what you are trying to do

Comment: I am looping through the DataTable to insert its values to table B. Now if I have in the DataTable about 100 rows, there will be 100 insert statement in Table B, my question: is there any other way to insert these 100 rows with minimum insert statement like for example insert select statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could just have an insert-select statement with the literal 3:

```
INSERT INTO b ([col a] , [col b], [col x])
SELECT [col a], [col b], 3
FROM   a 
WHERE  id = 5
```